# Return row of the active cell in google sheets

Tags: javascript, google-sheets-api

I am trying to return the row of the active cell in google sheets so I can use it in another the formula of another cell.  I have found several simple scripts that supposedly do this but have not been able to get any of the to work.  I apologize in advance for my lack of understanding in the scripting environment.  I do very little programming and my past experience was 25+ years ago (not much has changed since then, right???).  Anyway, any help that you can give me would e greatly appreciated.  I have found this:

```
function GetActiveRow() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var range = s.getActiveRange();
  var row = range.getRow(); 
  var values = s.getRange( row + ':' + row ).getValues();  
  s.getRange('A1').offset(0, 0, 1, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
```

But when I enter that in as a script and try the formula =GetActiveRow() it returns an error that states:

> Error You do not have permission to call setValues (line 7)

I probably shouldn't be playing in the scripting area without a better understanding of it but this is the only simple script I need.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi Spurz! Welcome to Stack Overflow :) What was the error that you got when you typed that in?

Comment: Error
You do not have permission to call setValues (line 7).

Comment: Okay! If you add that error message into your answer, it may help people who see this question to help you. I have enough reputation on this site that they asked me to help set you up since you're a new user, but unfortunately I don't have enough experience with Google Sheets to answer your question :(     If you do have more questions on how to improve your question or how the site works, feel free to comment below and I'll try to help.

Comment: I may be trying to cram an ould-school thought process into a place where there is a simpler solution.  What I am hoping to do is return the row number of the active cell as it moves around (i.e. using a function in cell a1 that tells me the row of the active cell as it moves around.

Comment: Have you found [this](https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/docs/hZDDuQpCNGE/7IkLBlSddXEJ)? Did it help?

Comment: I edited my original post to include the error message.

Comment: Did the link I found help at all? I'll repaste it here: https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/docs/hZDDuQpCNGE/7IkLBlSddXEJ

Comment: It did not, I need the data for the active cell but in a separate cell.

Comment: Does `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getActiveCell().getValue()` work? (This is from the same thread I linked to, just a [different response](https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/docs/hZDDuQpCNGE/gklWOpJagcEJ))

Comment: Sorry I had to step away but that one gives me:  TypeError: Cannot find function getActiveSheet in object function getActiveSpreadsheet() {/* */}. (line 2, file "Code")

Comment: Looks like that code was missing a set of parentheses. Does `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getActiveCell().getValue()` work?

Comment: (Also, you can put a backtick before and after your code, and it will make it look nice. For example, `this has a backtick before it and after it`, and `this only has a back tick before it.)

Comment: The documentation for Google Apps Script is really nice. If you're not finding what you're looking for, you could probably search for keywords within the documentation. Here's the class returned by the function `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()`: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet

Comment: Thanks for the Google Apps Script reference.  I'll read through there and see what I can find.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a sample code for you.

```
function onOpen() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  var getActiveRow = [{name: "getActiveRow", functionName: "fetchActiveRow"}];
     ss.addMenu("customMenu", getActiveRow);
};

function fetchActiveRow(){ 
     var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
     var row = ss.getActiveSheet().getActiveRange().getRow();

     var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
     var response = ui.alert("active row is " + row);
}
```

This creates a custom menu button on your spreadsheet named **customMenu** which contains **getActiveRow** button. When clicked, it will prompt you of the current active row in the sheet. Try it and modify as you please.

Comment: Thanks for the sample code.  It works as you describe.  I'll work through it to see if I can modify it for what I need.  Good information!